# jQuery "Google Loader" analog for personal site libs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loader

So I wonder how to get rid of 20 `<script>` tags on each html page in order to replace them with one script include and one line to load main js script for that page, one which would load all needed... Is there any such or alike plugin for jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)